# Sharing RMarkdown scripts in quarto pages

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto

I like to share R and RMarkdown scripts in a public quarto page. I render the page in **RStudio** using the function `quarto_render()`. The scripts to share are contained in a folder called **documents**. Unfortunately, `quarto_render()` is also rendering the RMarkdown file I would like to share.

**Question:**
Can I disable rendering of *.Rmd files or add files as exceptions that may not be rendered?

**Minimal Example:**

Files to be shared are in a subfolder `documents/`.

`documents/example.Rmd` (this file should not be rendered)

```
---
title: My First RMarkdown Document
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    self_contained: true
---

# Basics

## The Header

The **head** is *written* in `yaml` language.

## Hyperlink

[Tutorial for Markdown](https://www.markdowntutorial.com/)

## Picture

![nice picture](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e6/Iris_rhizome_p1150371.jpg)
```

`documents/example.R` (As reference to observe desired behavior)

```r
# Explore the content of a data frame
head(iris)
tail(iris)
str(iris)
summary(iris)
```

`index.qmd`

```
---
title: "My Homepage"
---

# Distributed Resources

In this page you can download [this R script](documents/example.R) and
[this RMarkdown sript](documents/example.Rmd).
```

`_quarto.yml` (page settings)

```
project:
  type: website
  output-dir: docs
  preview: 
    port: 4200
    browser: true

website:
  title: ""

format:
  html:
    theme: litera
    toc: true
```

In the RStudio session I use following code to render and preview the page:

```
library(quarto)
quarto_render()
quarto_preview()
```

Note that the R-script will be downloaded by the link at the homepage but the RMarkdown file will be rendered to a page but I like to share the RMarkdown source in the same way as the R-script.

Answer (score 0):

With your reproducible example, I got unrendered RMarkdown source, instead of a rendered page, so maybe the problem lies elsewhere. Nonetheless, if you want Quarto files to not be rendered, the file name should start with a low dash (_):

```
Go to [unrendered page](documents/_norender.qmd)
Go to [rendered page](documents/render.qmd)
```

Comment: I was guessing either a setting in `_quarto.yml` or an argument in `quarto_render()`. In fact, I was surprised that **.Rmd** are rendered at all.